# ojInput date issue with storing and retrieving from oracle DB

Tags: oracle-jet

I have used a ojInputDate field in my html form. The first time I save the form the date field value is getting stored in oracle sql Date in db. But when I reopen the form again for editing I am unable to edit it. How can I handle the OjInput date and oracle sql Date types

Comment: please share your code of how you save and populate your form so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement the REST API? The API likely uses JSON and JSON doesn't support dates. Most often, dates are converted to ISO 8601 strings as they move between the client and database. It's crucial to understand what happens with time zones when these conversions happen.

Here's [a link to a series](https://jsao.io/2016/08/working-with-dates-in-javascript-json-and-oracle-database/) where I cover this in detail. If you're using Oracle REST data services or the Node.js driver, then you should find the info you're looking for. Otherwise, please provide some more details so we can better help.